# VSCode Java stuck on "Importing projects"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a java program in VSCode, but it's just stuck on Importing projects. When I click "check details" it doesn't do anything, and when I try to view the output for "Language Support for Java" or "Language Support for Java (Syntax Server)", the output is blank.

KDE Neon 5.27
VSCode 1.75.1
Language Support for Java v1.15.0

Comment: Please share some reproduce steps or a sample project.

Comment: There are no steps apart from the ones mentioned. This happens with all java files, including ones that I know worked before. I just press "Run Java" or "Debug Java" and it gets stuck on Importing projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by downgrading Language Support for Java to v1.14.0. It seems v1.15.0 is broken.